# Java - XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java

I've a class with @XmlRootElement¸annotation

```
@XmlRootElement
     class Point {
        int x;
        int y;
        Point(int _x,int _y) {x=_x;y=_y;}
     }
```

Is there a function that produce the relative xml like?

```
 <point>
   <x> 3 
   <y> 5 
 </point>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'function' that binds your java class with an XML. It is the JAXB API in Java SE that generates XML out of the java class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` annotation. Please read the details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html).